# SQL Invalid Syntax in Java but not in Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Why does this statement work fine in workbench but not in Java.

```
SET @sqlstmt := IF( @exist <= 0, 'select ''INFO: Key does not exist.''', 'ALTER TABLE `SOMETABLE` DROP FOREIGN KEY `SOMEKEY`');
```

In Java I get

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @sqlstmt := IF( @exist <= 0, 'select ''INFO: Key does not exist.''', 'ALTER ' at line 1
```

Comment: Those quotes look weird. Shouldn't it be `"` instead of two single quotes?

Comment: have you tried simplifying the query to isolate the part causing the error?

Comment: And do you know what JDBC uses as delimiter?

Comment: I had thought a single quote should be escaped by a single quote when already inside single quotes.  Isn't that true?

Comment: I haven't seen it before. Could you try to escape these quotes not with other quotes but with backslashes?

Comment: I believe its using the user-defined variables in java... i had the same issue with python and mysql.. test without the variable and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be the fact that multiple statements were being executed (separated by semicolons).  In JDBC MYSQL you need `allowMultiQueries=true`